# What effect does setting breakpoints in gdb have on the address space?

Tags: memory, gdb, breakpoints

I recently read a text regarding buffer overflows that mentioned that setting breakpoints can offset your memory addresses a bit. I think I ran into this issue the other day when attempting to overwrite an EIP: the exploit seemed to work when I didn't set a breakpoint, but caused a segfault when a breakpoint was set. What happened?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recently read a text regarding buffer overflows that mentioned that setting breakpoints can offset your memory addresses a bit.

Either you didn't understand what that text was saying, or the text is wrong. It's hard to say which of the two possibilities is true, since you didn't provide a link to the text, or an actual quote.

Update:

> http://www.deadc0de.info/2009/11/08/solution-level5-of-smashthestack-io/
>
> "as I said above, we have our return address completely overwritten on
> the stack with C's (0x43). However, when you set your breakpoint on
> printf() the address may change."

That statement is bogus. Setting a breakpoint *can not and will not* change the stack location where `%ebp` and the return address are stored.

Setting a breakpoint does not normally affect memory layout, but may affect page protections: in order to insert a breakpoint, the debugger will usually do `ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, ...)`. That may or may not cause the `.text` page with the breakpoint writable (depending on the OS).

> What happened?

You have not provided sufficient data to answer that question.

Comment: http://www.deadc0de.info/2009/11/08/solution-level5-of-smashthestack-io/

"as I said above, we have our return address completely overwritten on the stack with C's (0x43). However, when you set your breakpoint on printf() the address may change. Make sure to use disass main to be certain of the address it's located at. If we step we can see the same result as last time we checked:"